# Can't send email via gmail servers, operation times out

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gmail

**EDIT**
Just a problem with the mail server not responding in time, I tried with a 3rd provider and it worked fine.
**END EDIT**

I'm trying to send a user registration email to my new users.

For testing purposes I switched to using Gmail's SMTP server for this as I figured maybe my mail provider is blocking the request somewhere but the problem persists.

All I know is that the `SmtpClient.Send()` call is timing out.  Here's my code:

```
public void SendEmail(string To, string Subject, string Body)
{
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(server, port);
    smtp.Credentials =
        new NetworkCredential("<my google account>", "<my google password>");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    using (MailMessage msg = 
        new MailMessage("<my private email account>", To, Subject, Body))
    {
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        smtp.Send(msg);
    }
}
```

Here's the stack trace:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException was caught
>   HResult=-2146233088
>   Message=The operation has timed out.
>   Source=System
>   StackTrace:
>
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>   at Ortund.Utilities.Mail.SendEmail(String To, String Subject, String Body)
>   in e:\Development\Base\Ortund.Utilities\Mail.cs:line 91
>   at Ortund.Utilities.ServiceMail.SendUserRegistrationEmail(User Source)
>   in r:\Users\Ortund\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OrtundWeb\Utilities\ServiceMail.cs:line 102
>   at OrtundWeb.Controllers.UserController.Post(User Source)
>   in r:\Users\Ortund\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OrtundWeb\Controllers\UserController.cs:line 63
>   InnerException:

Not particularly helpful... I figured maybe connection was failing because of SSL or credentials so I added those in with no change...

Anyone got any suggestions here because I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

They are blocking an application trying to send out emails as you (as they should be). Just send the emails out from your own server and set the replyTo property to your gmail email address and it will look like it came from your account.

Answer (score 0):

I also use the GMail SMTP server for testing. I use the following in VB.NET

```
    '*****For testing using GMail smtp server****** Comment out for production
    'Smtpclient to send the mail message

    sSMTP = "smtp.gmail.com"
    SmtpMail.Port = 587        '587     'For some reason vb.net doesn't like port 465.  Access does.
    SmtpMail.EnableSsl = True
    SmtpMail.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    SmtpMail.Timeout = 30000    'An Int32 that specifies the time-out value in milliseconds. The default value is 100,000 (100 seconds). 

    SmtpMail.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "gmail account name")
```